# Google Cloud gsutil instructions say update but there is no update command

Tags: gsutil, google-cloud-platform

```
On this page: 

https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install?hl=ja#install

The gsutil install recommends, right after install, running

gsutil update

which returns

CommandException: Invalid command "update".

Am I just seeing incorrect documentation? Is there some other way to update?

Checking on 'usage' doesn't mention there being any update command:

Usage: gsutil [-d][-D] [-h header]... [-m] [command [opts...] args...] [-q]
Available commands:
  acl            Get, set, or change bucket and/or object ACLs
  cat            Concatenate object content to stdout
  compose        Concatenate a sequence of objects into a new composite object.
  config         Obtain credentials and create configuration file
  cors           Set a CORS XML document for one or more buckets
  cp             Copy files and objects
  defacl         Get, set, or change default ACL on buckets
  du             Display object size usage
  help           Get help about commands and topics
  lifecycle      Get or set lifecycle configuration for a bucket
  logging        Configure or retrieve logging on buckets
  ls             List providers, buckets, or objects
  mb             Make buckets
  mv             Move/rename objects and/or subdirectories
  notification   Configure object change notification
  perfdiag       Run performance diagnostic
  rb             Remove buckets
  rm             Remove objects
  setmeta        Set metadata on already uploaded objects
  stat           Display object status
  test           Run gsutil tests
  version        Print version info about gsutil
  versioning     Enable or suspend versioning for one or more buckets
  web            Set a main page and/or error page for one or more buckets

Additional help topics:
  acls           Working With Access Control Lists
  anon           Accessing Public Data Without Credentials
  crc32c         CRC32C and Installing crcmod
  creds          Credential Types Supporting Various Use Cases
  dev            Contributing Code to gsutil
  metadata       Working With Object Metadata
  naming         Object and Bucket Naming
  options        Top-Level Command-Line Options
  prod           Scripting Production Transfers
  projects       Working With Projects
  subdirs        How Subdirectories Work
  support        Google Cloud Storage Support
  versions       Object Versioning and Concurrency Control
  wildcards      Wildcard Names

Use gsutil help  for detailed help.

EDIT:

It is gsutil version 3.42
```

Comment: What platform are you running on? On CentOS 6, I have `gsutil` 3.42 and the `update` command is there. Alternatively, consider instead installing [Google Cloud SDK](https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/) which includes `gsutil` and other tools and then run `gcloud components update`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a very old version?

Try `gsutil version` to see yours.

you can check release notes here:

```
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/blob/master/CHANGES.md
```